# create a column to accumulate the data in an array psypark

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I need to create a field to accumulate the data in an array.
I have the following dataframe:

```
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
|localSymbol_drop|end_window_drop    |detect_DRM|last_detect_price_DRM|
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:36:30|NO        |NA                   |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:37:00|NO        |NA                   |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:37:30|YES       |211.85               |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:38:00|NO        |NA                   |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:38:30|NO        |NA                   |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:40:30|NO        |NA                   |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:41:00|YES       |211.91               |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:42:00|NO        |NA                   |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:42:30|YES       |211.83               |
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

and the result will be:

```
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|localSymbol_drop|end_window_drop    |detect_DRM|last_detect_price_DRM|accum_array                             |
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:36:30|NO        |NA                   |[NA]                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:37:00|NO        |NA                   |[NA,NA]                                 |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:37:30|YES       |211.85               |[NA,NA,211.85]                          |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:38:00|NO        |NA                   |[NA,NA,211.85,NA]                       |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:38:30|NO        |NA                   |[NA,NA,211.85,NA,NA]                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:40:30|NO        |NA                   |[NA,NA,211.85,NA,NA,NA]                 |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:41:00|YES       |211.91               |[NA,NA,211.85,NA,NA,NA,211.91]          |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:42:00|NO        |NA                   |[NA,NA,211.85,NA,NA,NA,211.91,NA]       |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:42:30|YES       |211.83               |[NA,NA,211.85,NA,NA,NA,211.91,NA,211.83]|
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Any idea? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my solution you first need to create an index on your dataframe:

```
1)
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.orderBy("last_detect_price_DRM") 
df = df.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w))
```

When you have an index on your dataframe you need to get all values from the column you want to accumulate and sort that list(so that it is in the same order as your dataframe):

```
2)
my_list = 
df.select(f.collect_list('last_detect_price_DRM')).first()[0]
my_list.sort()
```

Now you just need to create an UserDefinedFunction which takes the index as an input and returns all elements in the list till that given index. After that you just need to call the function withColumn('columnName', udf) on your dataframe

```
3)
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType

def custom_func(index):
    return my_list[0:index]


custom_func = udf(custom_func, ArrayType(StringType()))

df = df.withColumn('acc', custom_func(col('index')))
```

That will accumulate all values in a given column.

```
1.
+------+------+
|    _1|    _2|
+------+------+
|  Java| 20000|
|Python|100000|
| Scala|  3000|
+------+------+

2.
 +------+------+-----+
|    _1|    _2|index|
+------+------+-----+
|Python|100000|    1|
|  Java| 20000|    2|
| Scala|  3000|    3|
+------+------+-----+

3.
+------+------+-----+--------------------+
|    _1|    _2|index|                 acc|
+------+------+-----+--------------------+
|Python|100000|    1|            [100000]|
|  Java| 20000|    2|     [100000, 20000]|
| Scala|  3000|    3|[100000, 20000, 3...|
+------+------+-----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, without udf function.

First of all I calculate an index:

```
win = Window.partitionBy('localSymbol_drop').orderBy('end_window_drop')
historical_trends = historical_trends.withColumn("index", f.row_number().over(win))
```

then I get the ordered list

```
list_last_detect_price_DRM = historical_trends\
    .orderBy('end_window_drop')\
    .groupby('localSymbol_drop')\
    .agg(
        f.collect_list("last_detect_price_DRM").alias('list_last_detect_price_DRM')
    ).select(
        f.col('list_last_detect_price_DRM'),
        f.col('localSymbol_drop').alias('localSymbol_other_drop')
    )
```

when I have the ordered list what I do is a join to the original df with slice function:

```
historical_trends = \
    historical_trends            \
    .join(list_last_detect_price_DRM,
        on=[
            (historical_trends.localSymbol_drop == list_last_detect_price_DRM.localSymbol_other_drop)
        ],
        how='left').distinct()\
    .withColumn(
        "correct_list_last_detect_price_DRM", f.expr("slice(list_last_detect_price_DRM,1,index)")
    ).drop('list_last_detect_price_DRM','localSymbol_other_drop')
```

and the result is:

```
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|localSymbol_drop|end_window_drop    |detect_DRM|last_detect_price_DRM|index|correct_list_last_detect_price_DRM                                                                                                          |
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:36:30|NO        |NA                   |1    |[NA]                                                                                                                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:37:00|NO        |NA                   |2    |[NA, NA]                                                                                                                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:37:30|YES       |211.85               |3    |[NA, NA, 211.85]                                                                                                                            |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:38:00|NO        |NA                   |4    |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA]                                                                                                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:38:30|NO        |NA                   |5    |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA]                                                                                                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:39:00|NO        |NA                   |6    |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA]                                                                                                                |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:39:30|NO        |NA                   |7    |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA]                                                                                                            |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:40:00|NO        |NA                   |8    |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA]                                                                                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:40:30|NO        |NA                   |9    |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA]                                                                                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:41:00|YES       |211.91               |10   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91]                                                                                            |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:41:30|NO        |NA                   |11   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA]                                                                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:42:00|NO        |NA                   |12   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA]                                                                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:42:30|YES       |211.83               |13   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83]                                                                            |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:43:00|NO        |NA                   |14   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA]                                                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:43:30|YES       |211.75               |15   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75]                                                                |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:44:00|NO        |NA                   |16   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA]                                                            |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:44:30|NO        |NA                   |17   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA]                                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:45:00|NO        |NA                   |18   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA]                                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:45:30|YES       |211.72               |19   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72]                                            |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:46:00|NO        |NA                   |20   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA]                                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:46:30|NO        |NA                   |21   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA]                                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:47:00|NO        |NA                   |22   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA]                                |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:47:30|YES       |211.81               |23   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA, 211.81]                        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:48:00|NO        |NA                   |24   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA, 211.81, NA]                    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:48:30|NO        |NA                   |25   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA, 211.81, NA, NA]                |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:49:00|YES       |211.93               |26   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA, 211.81, NA, NA, 211.93]        |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:49:30|NO        |NA                   |27   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA, 211.81, NA, NA, 211.93, NA]    |
|BABA            |2021-06-15 16:50:00|NO        |NA                   |28   |[NA, NA, 211.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 211.91, NA, NA, 211.83, NA, 211.75, NA, NA, NA, 211.72, NA, NA, NA, 211.81, NA, NA, 211.93, NA, NA]|
+----------------+-------------------+----------+---------------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```